# How to update Cuke4Duke JRuby gems via Ant

Tags: cucumber, jruby

I have a Java project that is using Cucumber for BDD.  This morning the entire thing came to a crashing halt, I can no longer install gems, I get the dreaded "undefined class/module YAML::Syck::DefaultKey" error. I know that I need to update the version of Rubygem being used, but I haven't been able to do that.

I have searched the web and StackOverflow, but haven't found anything that works for my situation.  I'm using ant for the entire process.  It downloads the JRuby jar (I've tried 1.6.1, 1.6.3 and 1.6.4).

When I try to update rubygem using:

```
java -jar ./lib/org.jruby/jruby-complete-1.6.1.jar -S gem update --system
```

...I get the error:

```
undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass.
```

I've tried installing cucumber first, but I get the same error message.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this going?  I would consider switching to cucumber-jvm but it isn't released to the Maven repository yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, it's not quite what I was hoping for, but it works.  Fortunately I had installed these gems a few months ago in an actual RVM Gemset for JRuby 1.5.5.  I went to that gemset and rebuilt all of the gems.  I copied the gem directories to a temp lcoation and then copied each gemspec files to the appropriate directory and ran `gem build xxxxx.gemspec` in each directory.  This created new gem files which I am able to serve from a plain webserver.

It may be possible to grab gems from a newer install and rebuild with an older install, I didn't try that myself, but it might work for you.